# drawing text on top of model while moving camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to be able to draw text on top of model.

I have a scene like the following;
[image]

I want to be able to add text on top of the green lines. However, I couldn't be able to display 2d text with the right projection. I have a moving camera and the middle car is moving too.

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

This makes the text appear at the back of the camera (meaning smaller z value). I have all the cars position in `Vector3`. I have the following code for sidecars;

```
public class SideCar extends Car {

  public enum Side {
    LEFT, RIGHT
  }

  protected Side side;
  protected String plate;
  protected ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
  protected Vector3 sideCarV3;
  protected Texture texture;

  public SideCar(AssetManager assetManager, Side side, String plate) {

    super(assetManager);
    this.id = "side_car";
    this.side = side;
    this.plate = plate;

    if (side == Side.LEFT) {
      instance.transform.translate(-35f, 0f, 10f);
    } else { // right
      instance.transform.translate(35f, 0f, 10f);
    }

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    sideCarV3 = new Vector3();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/avenir.png"), true); // true enables mipmaps
    texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
  }

  @Override
  public void renderModel(float deltaTime, Scene scene) {

    super.renderModel(deltaTime, scene);
    scene.modelBatch().render(instance, scene.environment());
    //scene.modelBatch().render(texture, scene.environment());

    // public final void line (float x, float y, float z, float x2, float y2, float z2)
    sideCarV3 = instance.transform.getTranslation(sideCarV3);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(scene.camera().combined);
    shapeRenderer.identity();

    if (side == Side.LEFT) {
      shapeRenderer.line(2.5f, 0f, sideCarV3.z, 2.5f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z);
      shapeRenderer.line(2.5f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z, 2.4f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z);
    } else {
      shapeRenderer.line(-2.5f, 0f, sideCarV3.z, -2.5f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z);
      shapeRenderer.line(-2.5f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z, -2.4f, 1.5f, sideCarV3.z);
    }

    shapeRenderer.end();

  }

  @Override
  public void renderSprite(float deltaTime, Scene scene) {

    instance.transform.getTranslation(sideCarV3);

    if (side == Side.LEFT) {

    } else {
      infoFont.draw(
          scene.spriteBatch(),
          String.format(Locale.US, "%d km/h", (int) (speed * 100)), sideCarV3.x, sideCarV3.y + 5f
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas to put the texts right top of the green lines ?

Comment: Do you want the text to shrink with distance or all be the same size on screen regardless of distance?

Comment: The text doesn't need to shrink .The end result will be showing the nearest side car text and the green shape